# Is `var self = this` considered a code smell?

Tags: javascript

Currently watching "Advanced Javascript" on pluralsight. In the "Object Oriented" part of the course there is a section where Kyle has me totally lost:

```
NotesManager.prototype.showHelp = function() {
    this.$help.show();

    document.addEventListener("click",function() __handler__(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        document.removeEventListener("click", __handler__,true);
        this.hideHelp();
    },true);
};
```

The `this` reference will now be the button which will cause `this.hideHelp();` to not work. He first tries a hard binding solution to fix the problem:

```
NotesManager.prototype.showHelp = function() {
    this.$help.show();

    document.addEventListener("click",function() __handler__(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        document.removeEventListener("click", __handler__,true);
        this.hideHelp();
    }.bind(this),true);
};
```

Which he says fixes the `this` problem but causes another problem.Above a named function is used so it can be unbound. But he states the name of the function is not what is now bound. The function that is bound is that new hard bound function so it can't be unbound since we don't have a reference to the hard bound function. Huh? Can anyone explain. He doesn't go into the details.

Right after that he explains the best way to fix the issue is to use a self reference:

```
NotesManager.prototype.showHelp = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.$help.show();

    document.addEventListener("click",function() __handler__(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

        document.removeEventListener("click", __handler__,true);
        self.hideHelp();
    },true);
};
```

Typically he says he recommends avoiding doing this because it indicates a code smell but he said this is one of those rare circumstances where its the best solution. He goes on to say that your shooting yourself in the foot because you went to trouble to implement the `this` mechanism and then you fell back to lexical scope. He said that people who use self references generally don't understand how the mechanisms work. I've never heard the self reference being a code smell. I've seen it used extensively. Why is generally indicate a code smell? Maybe it should only be used when you have an event handler?

Comment: `.bind` returns a new function, do `__handler_.bind(this) !== __handler__`. As for the rest, it's just one person's opinion.

Comment: He could easily have used `var __handler__ = function(evt) { … }.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1):

It's a common scope problem in Javascript, which the new fat arrow notation should help with. In my experience, everyone hates using `self = this`, but does it anyway - mostly because it stays readable.

The fat arrow notation will help tremendously with this issue, and with its introduction using **`self` is *becoming* a code smell**.

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own `this` value
>   (a new object in case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the context object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.). This proved to be annoying with an
>   object-oriented style of programming.

-[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions) (`Code` emphasis mine.)

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up your claim or is this just your opinion?

Comment: Code smells are by definition subjective, unless you're operating under a specific paradigm. I almost voted to close this question as opinion-based, but I believe code smells are an important topic that skirt the edge of SO's opinion-based flags. Vote to close if you feel that passionately.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: changed `lexical` scope to `functional` scope
The reason Why it could be considered code smell is because everything in JavaScript is functional scoped. But, `this` is dynamically scoped.

```
void foo()
{
    int floo = 1;

    void foo2()
    {
        console.log(floo);
    }
}
```

every inner level can access the outer level.

But with `this` it's the opposite, it can't do that.

```
void foo()
{
    //this refers to foo()
    console.log(this)

    void foo2()
    {   //this refers to foo2()
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

and people can get confused but to me it's not a big deal.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: 1. The code you've written is not valid JavaScript. 2. JavaScript has _functional scope_, not lexical scope.